# Id of Image in touchMoved Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I m a currently working on gestures in an Iphone application

i used the touch gesture function which are working properly.

my touch gesture functions are working on an Image (Like Dragging) 
i want to ask is there a way to get the id of that image which is currently in touch gesture function

the touchMoved Function is like that

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Calculate and store offset, and pop view into front if needed
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
// During movement, update the transform to match the touches
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    // Calculate offset
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
    float dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
    CGPoint newcenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy);


    // Remove Image (set Cordinated out of View)
    if ((newcenter.x <= 9) || (newcenter.y >= 403)) {
       //NSLog(@"Delete Image");
       newcenter.x = 1000;
        newcenter.y = 1000;

 }


     self.center = newcenter;
    //    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To detect your touched imageView**

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if([[touch valueForKey:@"view"] tag] > 0)
    {
        yourImageView=[touch valueForKey:@"view"]; //here's the magic :)
    }
}
```

Comment: well this what i thought but the problem is i dont have an ImageView in the Class which implements this function. Instead  that class is a sub class of UIImageView.  What i do is that from my Root View Controller i Call this Function                                        NSString *whichFlower = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"image1.gif",@"image2.png",nil] objectAtIndex:i++];
    
    DragView *dragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithImage:img];                                 and From my Dragger Class i use                                                 - (id) initWithImage: (UIImage *) anImage

Comment: @Addicted, on what you want to detect your images?

Comment: Say we have two images on the screen currently. when the user drags on of the image the touchImage Function will be called. say the image is draged to coords say  x = 9 y = 50 the image is saved in an array which will be processed in other class

Comment: @Addicted, you need to set Tag for individual images which you are showing using different UIImageViews on your view.

Comment: yes u are right.. but the problem is that the name (of images) are stored in an NSArray and i m passing it to my class in form of Strings which are collected to a UIImage. and  UIImage donot hve property of Tag.

Comment: @Addicted, Okey.. I understand, you can do one more thing, when user touch on any of imageviews you can store that tag into different array. And that array can be pass with images array.