# Finding the array indexes of objects on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, math

I have a pie chart made up of 12 slices, which are all within an array. The idea is to be able to touch any particular slice, receive its correct index position within the array, and scale that slice up and down. I have the creation of the slices done, as well as the scaling, but the math behind selecting the correct index has stumped me.

The current code (slicesArray = 12) I have that returns the incorrect index number is:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
int index = atan2f(point.x-self.view.center.x, point.y-self.view.center.y) * self.slicesArray.count / (2*M_PI);
```

This image shows the slices, with the black text representing the correct index numbers, while the white text represents what the above code returns.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the type of slices? are you using ImageView?

Comment: They are UIBezierPath's inside UIView's. Each slice has its own UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an UIImageView to show all images, then [Here's my answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871695/1229954).
What you need to do is setTag for individual UIImageView. It will identify touched UIImageView. Its tag will index for your array, and you can also pass it to NSArray to get value from it.

Comment: It can be work for individual UIView. Just replace UIImageView with UIView (from my above answer) and you will get your result.

Comment: Genius! I had one issue with the main view scaling my slice at index 0. I set self.view to -1 and that fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop to find out which UIView is being touched

```
UIView *selectedPie;

for (UIView *pie in slicesArray) {

 if(CGRectContainsPoint(pie.frame, point)) {

selectedPie = pie;
break;

    }

}
```

and then scale the selectedPie. Hope this helps